# Lowercase day of week in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby 1.9 there is a [rich `strftime` function](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) which enables lots of different formats. I can understand how to get `Sun` and `SUN` as days of the week using `%a` and `%^a` respectively, but I would like to get `sun`. Is there any way of using `strftime` to get a lowercase day of week?

NOTE: I specifically want an `strftime` solution so that I can put the formatting in (and only in) the locale file and then use the `l` function alone in my views.

Comment: What's wrong with lowercasing the result?

Comment: it means you can't put it in your locale file! this is a big difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using css to make it lowercase, and combined that with the localize version.

Answer (score 0):

Just chain it with downcase

```
t = Time.now
t.strftime­("%a").dow­ncase
```

I know it's going to be a pain to concatenate it with other parts of your format but I'm pretty sure you can't do this using flags alone. There's a case change flag `#` but it can't be used to reverse the result of `^` or itself so

```
t.strftime­("%##a %#^a")
```

will just print `SUN SUN`